# How to add headers to SAML/ SOAP request

Tags: java, soap, header, saml

I am automating a soap service where I need to send SAML request with headers.

```
String endpoint ="https://xyz";
File  xml = new File("path of xml") ;
String req = FileUtils. readFileToString(xml) ;
SOAPConnectionFactory fact = 
SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection conn = fact.createConnection();
URL end = new URL(endpoint) ;
SOAPMessage Sr = messageFactory.createMesaage(new 
javax.xml.soap.Mineheaders(), New  ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8))));
SOAPMessage soapRes = connection.call(Sr,end);
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
soapRes.writeTo(out);
```

This is the code I am using. 
Now I want to set some headers how should I set them for the request?
HEADERS:

POST : afahagajahs
Host : hsghgfgg
Cobtent-type : text
Content-Length : 258
SoapAction : ""

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAPHeader which could be retrieved from SOAPMessage object. See following APIs :

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPHeader.html